# Underscore + _.filter filtering a list based on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'd like to filter out food options, based on radio button selects.

[image]

As an example, I have a list of foods that can show up in a dropdown list. Some users have permission to view fruits, others vegetables and some both. The list returns all foods.

Depending on their permissions, I'd like to filter out the list based on f.food_type using Underscore's *.filter/*.reject or pure JavaScript.

```
  $.get('/api/foods', function(foods) {
    return $foodList.select2({
      placeholder: 'Select food',
      data: foods.map(function(f) {
        return {
          id: f.id,
          text: f.food_name + ' [' + f.food_type + ']'
        };
      })
    });
  });
```

Dropdown for a user who has permissions to see fruit and vegetables. I'd like to hide one or the other based on their permissions.

[image]

I am using the Underscore library, but don't know how to do this with _.filter. Is there perhaps even a simpler way to filter the list based on radio buttons? Ie. if clicked '#vegetables', only show list of vegetables?

Comment: I see this question asked at least the 3rd time here. Are you dropping and recreating it every time?

Comment: Nobody can help without knowing how roles are defined , and what the rules are. Also, why aren't you doing this filtering in the API in the first place?

Comment: Charlie, just updated the question mate to show you what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example showing a couple of ways to filter based on other values. I need to assume you are already loading your users permissions somewhere. and fetching the value of the selected food type somewhere else.

You should be able to adapt these for your purpose. You can use the result of one as a base for the next, of course.

```js
var foods = [
    {food_name: 'banana', food_type: 'good'},
    {food_name: 'burger', food_type: 'crap'},
    {food_name: 'fries', food_type: 'crap'},
    {food_name: 'butter', food_type: 'ok'},
    {food_name: 'apple', food_type: 'good'}
]

//ensure you have access to user permissions
var userFoodTypes = ['good', 'ok'];

var filteredToPermissions = _.filter(foods, function(f) {
    return _.contains(userFoodTypes, f.food_type);
});

alert(filteredToPermissions.length);
alert(filteredToPermissions[0].food_type);

var filteredToSelected = _.where(foods, {food_type: 'ok'});

alert(filteredToSelected[0].food_type);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Danny! I ended up going with a modified version of your answer and it works well. Appreciate it mate!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the radios are `name="food_type"` and the values are identical to the food types in your data you can add a simple condition to  `map`

```
var selectedFoodType = $('input[name=food_type]:checked').val();

// ajax left out for clarity

foods.map(function (f) {
    if (selectedFoodType === f.foodType) {
        return {
            id: f.id,
            text: f.food_name + ' [' + f.food_type + ']'
        };
    }
});
```

As for filtering by user roles only, some sort of hash map is needed as well as access to a variable that stores the current user type.

```
var roles ={  
   buyer  : ['vegetabes'],
   seller : ['fruits'],
   admin  : ['vegetabes','fruits']
}

var userType = someStoredUserObject.userType;
var allowedFoodTypes = roles[userType ];

foods.map(function (f) {
    if (allowedFoodTypes.indexOf(f.food_type) >-1) {
        return {
            id: f.id,
            text: f.food_name + ' [' + f.food_type + ']'
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Charlie, thanks so much for your answer! I was so close to getting this working, however, due to using Select2, didn't allow me to add the if conditional within the ajax request for data.

Comment: of course you can...it's the same map as in the question